# Performing a random addition between two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What I'm trying to do is get two different arrays, where the first array is just filled with zeros and second array would be populated by random numbers. I would like to perform an operation where only certain elements from the latter array are added to the array filled with zeros and the rest of elements within the former array remain as zero. I'm trying to get the addition done in a random way as well. I just added the code below as an example. I honestly don't know how to perform something like this and I would be very grateful for any help or suggestions! Thank you!

```
shape = (6, 3)
empty_array = np.zeros(shape)
random_array = 0.1 * np.random.randn(*empty_array)

sum = np.add(empty_array, random_array)
```

Comment: You might look into indexing by a boolean array. Then, for instance, you could do sum[values_to_change] = np.add(empty_array[values_to_change], random_array[values_to_change]). In this case, values_to_change would be a 6x3 array of True or False

Comment: just for clarification, you first generate a matrix of size shape filled with zeros. the second (random) array will be the same shape as this matrix? and if so ,then it will randomly add elements of the same index? or is it choosing to add numbers randomly from a 1d list ?

Comment: I will look into it. However, would T or F in the values_to_change array change for every iteration as well or would that be something that's consistent? I'm asking because the addition between the empty and random arrays will probably be done more than a 100 times. Thank you!

Comment: @RashanArshad, essentially only say 20% the values that are produced within the random array would be added to the array filled with zeros. The percent of values that are added to the empty array would be the only parameter controlled.

Comment: You need to clarify your code (maybe with an example of input/desired output). Also, do not use `sum` as a variable name, it is a keyword in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly from your comments, you want to create random numbers at random indices based on the threshold of some percent of whole array (you do not need to create a whole random array and use only a percent of it, such random number generation is usually costly in larger scales):

```
sz = shape[0]*shape[1]
#this is your for example 20% threshold
threshold = 0.2
#create random numbers and random indices
random_array = np.random.rand(int(threshold*sz))
random_idx = np.random.randint(0,sz,int(threshold*sz))

#now you can add this random_array to random indices of your desired array
empty_array.reshape(-1)[random_idx] += random_array
```

or another solution:

```
sz = shape[0]*shape[1]
#this is your for example 20% threshold
threshold = 0.2
random_array = np.random.rand(int(threshold*sz))
#pad with enough zeros and randomly shuffle and finally reshape it
random_array.resize(sz)
np.random.shuffle(random_array)

#now you can add this random_array to any array of your choice
empty_array += random_array.reshape(shape)
```

sample output:

```
[[0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.7397274 ]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.79541551]
 [0.75684113 0.         0.        ]]
```

Comment: The sample output you have provided is exactly what I'm looking for. However, when I try to run your code, I keep running into the following error: 
"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,3) (18,) (6,3)"

Comment: @AP_98 Thank you for catching that. The reshape was in the wrong line. Fixed it. Should work now.

Comment: @AP_98 You are welcome. I just updated the post with an even faster and shorter solution if performance is important to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a binary mask with the density `P`:

```
P = 0.5
# Repeat the next two lines as needed
mask = np.random.binomial(1, P, size = empty_array.size)\
         .reshape(shape).astype(bool)
empty_array[mask] += random_array[mask]
```

If you plan to add more random elements, you may want to re-generate the mask at each further iteration.